# Why does the default xcode class header import Foundation/Foundation.h?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

Default file:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface MyClass : NSObject

@end
```

My understanding is pre-compiled headers are included in every file.  Why doesn't this import just go into the pre-compiled headers?

Comment: My Xcode 5 doesn't appear to be including it in every class (it is included in the .pch file). I agree with you that this makes more sense than including it everywhere. The answer to your question is probably "an oversight on Apple's part" :)

Comment: Interesting, I'm on xcode 5 as well

Comment: A "prefix header" is a header that is automatically included in every file. A "precompiled header" is a cached copy of a header file that is optimized for the compiler's use.

Comment: @BlackRider happy to accept your answer if you post it as one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My Xcode 5 doesn't appear to be including it in every class (it is included in the .pch file). I agree with you that this makes more sense than including it everywhere. The answer to your question is probably "an oversight on Apple's part" :)

Answer (score 3):

There is no guarantee that *every* project have a .pch file that import Foundation.h so Xcode need to generate it to make sure new files always compile.

Also some people think it is good style to include header even it is already included in .pch file. Because you know exactly what headers are needed by this file. It also allow people to disable prefix header if needed.